# State transformations with a shapeless State monad

Tags: scala, scalaz, shapeless, state-monad, scalaz7

Scalaz State monad's [`modify`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/abbd0238972d71bd07724218d4f85341ab720389/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/State.scala#L31) has the following signature:

```scala
def modify[S](f: S => S): State[S, Unit]
```

This allows the state to be replaced by state of the same type, which does not work well when the state includes a shapeless value such as a `Record` whose type changes as new fields are added. In that case what we need is:

```scala
def modify[S, T](f: S => T): State[T, Unit]
```

What is a good way to adapt Scalaz's State monad to use shapeless state so that one can use Records as opposed to, say, the dreaded `Map[String, Any]`?

Example:

```scala
case class S[L <: HList](total: Int, scratch: L)

def contrivedAdd[L <: HList](n: Int): State[S[L], Int] =
  for {
    a <- init
    _ <- modify(s => S(s.total + n, ('latestAddend ->> n) :: s.scratch))
    r <- get
  } yield r.total
```

**Update:**

The full code for Travis's answer is [here](https://gist.github.com/ssimeonov/e61c40808d3cd13016c1).

Comment: How about `def modify[S, T](f: S => T): State[T, Unit] = State((s: S) => (f(s), ()))` ?

Comment: @knutwalker are you suggesting extending `State` and overloading `modify`?

Comment: No, just write this function anywhere in your code. There's no need to extend or overload anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`State` is a type alias for a more generic type `IndexedStateT` that's specifically designed to represent functions that change the state type as state computations:

```
type StateT[F[_], S, A] = IndexedStateT[F, S, S, A]
type State[S, A] = StateT[Id, S, A]
```

While it's not possible to write your `modify[S, T]` using `State`, it is possible with `IndexedState` (which is another type alias for `IndexedStateT` that fixes the effect type to `Id`):

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def transform[S, T](f: S => T): IndexedState[S, T, Unit] =
  IndexedState(s => (f(s), ()))
```

You can even use this in `for`-comprehensions (which has always seemed a little odd to me, since the monadic type changes between operations, but it works):

```
val s = for {
  a <- init[Int];
  _ <- transform[Int, Double](_.toDouble)
  _ <- transform[Double, String](_.toString)
  r <- get
} yield r * a
```

And then:

```
scala> s(5)
res5: scalaz.Id.Id[(String, String)] = (5.0,5.05.05.05.05.0)
```

In your case you might write something like this:

```
import shapeless._, shapeless.labelled.{ FieldType, field }

case class S[L <: HList](total: Int, scratch: L)

def addField[K <: Symbol, A, L <: HList](k: Witness.Aux[K], a: A)(
  f: Int => Int
): IndexedState[S[L], S[FieldType[K, A] :: L], Unit] =
  IndexedState(s => (S(f(s.total), field[K](a) :: s.scratch), ()))
```

And then:

```
def contrivedAdd[L <: HList](n: Int) = for {
  a <- init[S[L]]
  _ <- addField('latestAdded, n)(_ + n)
  r <- get
} yield r.total
```

(This may not be the best way of factoring out the pieces of the update operation, but it shows how the basic idea works.)

It's also worth noting that if you don't care about representing the state transformation as a state computation, you can just use `imap` on any old `State`:

```
init[S[HNil]].imap(s =>
  S(1, field[Witness.`'latestAdded`.T](1) :: s.scratch)
)
```

This doesn't allow you to use these operations compositionally in the same way, but it may be all you need in some situations.

Comment: Your answer, in addition to being elegant, holds a neat little gem inside it, which is the piece of `addField` that extends a record using a key and a value. The combination of the witness and `field[K](a)` is not obvious w/o reading the shapeless source.